# What's the best way to make the disabled attribute on an input reactive with Meteor helpers?

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, meteor, html-input

Is there a decent way to do this? Code looks like this:

```
<input type="radio"> Answer 1
<input type="radio"> Answer 2
```

I'd like them both to enable and disable based on a calculation from a Collection. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the optional `disabled` property as a helper.

html:

```
<input type="radio" {{isDisabled}}/>
```

js:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  isDisabled: function() {
    return shouldBeDisabled() ? 'disabled' : '';
  },
});
```